# On the substitution of inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
V&=&\displaystyle{4\cdot2\int_{-1}^y2\sqrt{1-y^2}\ \mathrm{d}y} \\[0.7em]
 &=&\displaystyle{16\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^{\arcsin(y)}\cos^2t \ \mathrm{d}t} \\[0.7em]
 &=&\displaystyle{\left[8\left(\arcsin(y)+y\sqrt{1-y^2}\ \right)+4\pi\right]}
\end{array}
$$

Here's an equation on my textbook. I don't know the details of the transformation between them, how the integral interval is transformed (I'm not very familiar with anti trigonometric functions)

Comment: Are you sure the first integral has upper limit $y$? It doesn't really make sense that way if your variable is also $y$.

Comment: This is part of the answer to an exercise in my textbook, which is about placing liquid in a horizontal cylindrical container with elliptical bottom. The elliptic equation is x ^ 2 / 4 + y ^ 2 = 1. When the liquid level passes through the point (0, y) (- 1 < = y < = 1), what is the volume of liquid in the container

Comment: I'm sure that the limit is y because I check my textbook......

Comment: In this case, the integration variable cannot be $y$. A variable cannot be both a free and a dumb variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the integral is correct as written, it's a bit confusing, because the $y$ in the upper limit of integration and the $y$ int the integrand are not the same variable.  In the upper limit, $y$ is an independent variable, representing the height of the liquid.  In the integrand, $y$ is a dummy variable, that we can replace by any other.

Doing the substitution is clearer if we first replace the dummy $y$ by some other dummy variable, say $u$.  $$V=16\int_{-1}^y\sqrt{1-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Now make the substitution, $u=\sin t$.  Then $\mathrm{d}u=\cos t\mathrm{d}t$, $\sqrt{1-u^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}=\cos t$.  (Because $t=\arcsin u$, we have $-\frac\pi2\leq t\leq\frac\pi2$, and $\cos t\geq0$, so we don't need to take the absolute value.)

To transform the limits of integration, just note that when $u=-1$, $t=\arcsin(-1)=-\frac\pi2$ and when $u=y$, $t=\arcsin y$. It's this very last point that may be a bit unclear if we don't change the dummy variable.  It would say, "When $y=y$, ...".

The formula for [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals) says $$\int_a^bf(\phi(t))\phi'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u,$$ assuming all hypotheses are satisfied.  In this case, we have $$\begin{align} 
f(u)&=\sqrt{1-u^2}\\
\phi(t)&=\sin t\\
a&=-\frac\pi2\\
b&=\arcsin y
\end{align}$$